# Manage data or queries for a web application dashboard

Tags: laravel, mariadb

I'm working on a maintenance project where I need to create a dashboard screen for a web application. It is built in Laravel / MariaDB. I am doing analysis on performance and I need to have these charts on the dashboard.

1. KPI count of 10 different modules for 7 days
2. Monthly KPI- Pivot Table (from 5 tables)
3. 2 Pie chart for today's work
4. Bar chart for weekly target

There are 300 users who use this web application. If I create a dashboard with the above charts, there will be many queries to load one page.

What is the best way to handle the dashboard data?

Comment: "there will be many queries to load one page" - well, yes - but what's wrong with that? Queries can be very fast if you design your database with performance in-mind (namely: by using indexes).

Comment: If a dashboard's data doesn't need to be updated on every page-load, then you could cache the dashboard's view-model in-memory or on-disk or something - then boom - instant load times until the data is considered stale.

Comment: @dai , is there any tool or for that ?